# Redirect https:IP address to https:localhost

Tags: java, https, localhost, ip, ip-address

I have a java application that fails to initialize because it cannot connect to destination IP in a remote server https://10.240.70.80/portal/nin/global.nin
I am already making port forwarding to connect to this server, however I need something in my computer to force the address to resolved as https://localhost:15040/portal/nin/global.nin
In this case it works as I test https://localhost:15040/portal/nin/global.nin in the browser and it connects , that's why I need this conversion in the application.

Comment: Redirect the traffic through a proxy like mitmproxy/Fiddler/Charles/Burp that supports HTTPS interception plus allows to rewrite/change the server URL.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, it worke  for https but for other protocol it didn't work. I used Fiddler "Host Remapping" 127.0.0.1:15040 10.240.70.80:443. This solved the problem but after that the application in my laptop tried to connect to 10.240.70.80:2181 with TCP which I can see in wireshark, I added another line in fidler for this new port 2181 but it didn't map it.

Comment: If you want to redirect all traffic you need a Linux system then use itables rules to redirect traffic. There are various post regarding that here on SO/Superuser.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, I have Windows 10 machine but I have linux subsystem installed in it. Can I use it ?

Comment: I don't think so: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4480